# Overwrite files when user open files with write access

Tags: vbscript

I am writing a VBScript to copy file from source to target. It works copy from source to target but if we are trying to overwrite the file to target and if any user open that same file in target it's not overwriting it.

Note: the user open the file has write access.

Could someone please help on this? Below is the function but have to delete file that are also open in destination.

```
Sub Clear_All_Files_And_SubFolders_In_Folder()
    'Delete all files and subfolders
    'Be sure that no file is open in the folder
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim MyPath As String

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Test"  '<< Change

    If Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then
        MyPath = Left(MyPath, Len(MyPath) - 1)
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(MyPath) = False Then
        MsgBox MyPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    'Delete files
    FSO.DeleteFile MyPath & "\*.*", True
    'Delete subfolders
    FSO.DeleteFolder MyPath & "\*.*", True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Several questions: Is this a multi-user path? What are you trying to accomplish - Something similar to Rsync? Is this an integrity script that makes sure the files stay the same? Additional clarification is needed to help.

Comment: For one thing, the code you posted is not VBScript. Is it VBA? Also, you can't replace/overwrite a file as long as someone has an open handle to it. You can use tools like [`handle`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle) to check for open handles. I wouldn't recommend forcibly closing open handles, though. I concur with Steve Kline: what do you want to accomplish by force-replacing the file(s)?

Comment: Hi, I want to forcefully close all the connection open on the files in destination so that source and destination will be un sync. Note: if any file open in destination and if we try to delete it's not happening.

Comment: Of course it's not happening. You cannot open, delete, or modify files to which some other process has an open handle.

Comment: how to close that connections..

Comment: is there any command to close all locks for the file/folder in server

Comment: how about psfile command?