# VB Script to unlock all files in remote

Tags: vbscript

Is there any way to unlock for all files inside a folder open by other user in remote.

using vbscript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overwrite files when user open files with write access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828435/overwrite-files-when-user-open-files-with-write-access)

Comment: Off-Topic - Basic administration of a file server

Answer (score 0):

You can't terminate that locally unless Locally means that you're on the server hosting the file share. Terminate the connection to the server via open sessions. If they're office documents, they need to be properly configured to allow more than one user to open them at once. Here's some scripts to unlock the files by terminating the sessions attached to those files.

### View Network Sessions/users - Alternatively use: net session

```
Set objConnection = GetObject(“WinNT://server/LanmanServer”)
Set Sessions = objConnection.Sessions
For Each session in Sessions
    Wscript.Echo “Computer: ” & session.Computer
    Wscript.Echo “Connected Time: ” & session.ConnectTime
    Wscript.Echo “Idle Time: ” & session.IdleTime
    Wscript.Echo “Name: ” & session.Name
    Wscript.Echo “User: ” & session.User
    Wscript.Echo
Next
```

### View Open Files for network session

```
Set objConnection = GetObject(“WinNT://server/LanmanServer”)
Set SessionFiles = objConnection.Resources
For Each objResource in SessionFiles
    Wscript.Echo “Path: ” & objResource.Path
    Wscript.Echo “User: ” & objResource.User
    Wscript.Echo
Next
```

### Terminate Session

```
Set objConnection = GetObject("WinNT://server/LanmanServer")
Set Sessions = objConnection.Sessions
For Each resource in Sessions
    'net session \\computername /delete /y
    Sessions.Remove(resource.Name)
Next
```